# "dplyr" doesn't know separate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am using R 3.5.3. When I run

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "a.b", "a.d", "b.c"))
df %>% 
  separate(df[1], c("A", "B"))
```

I got

> Error in separate(., df[1], c("A", "B")) : 
>         could not find function "separate"

I have installed **tidyr** and **dplyr** correctly. The same result appears after reinstalling the **tidyverse** and **dplyr**.

UPDATE: the same problem appears with

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "a.b", "a.d", "b.c"))
df %>% 
  separate(x, c("A", "B"))
```

Comment: Check the spellings of your packages and edit the question.`tidyr`,`dplyr`,`tidyverse`.

Comment: Just do `df %>% 
  separate(x, c("A", "B"))` or just specify `tidyr::separate`.

Comment: What do you mean "_UPDATE: the same problem appears..._"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: If R can't find the function then the library is not loaded. Check for and report any error messages after package install or `library()`

Comment: After reinstalling the packages  from the R GUI (not from R studio), it works. No idea about the reason, in the future I will install the packages from the GUI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to put `df[1]` in the `pipe`, try this :

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "a.b", "a.d", "b.c"))
df %>% 
  separate(x, c("A", "B"))
```

I am using

```
tidyr_0.8.1 
dplyr_0.7.8 
R 3.5.3
```

Comment: @MirkoDalleMarke did you try `tidyr::separate`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.

I had run the following code to install packages necessary for my script:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
```

but loading lubridate ahead of dplyr and tidyr interfered with the `{dplyr}` package. Removing `{lubridate}` and re-running the script from the beginning solved this issue.